# How can i apply colspan inside my nested thead component?

Tags: html, angular

I built the following stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y454qb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-header%2Ftable-header.component.css

As you can see I have parent table `table` which has one child component called `table-header`

If I write this code directly in my `table` component then my `th` `colspan` attribute will get applied
and will get the whole width of the table

```
  <thead>
    <th class="tableHeader" colspan="12">my table header</th>
  </thead>
```

but if I put the same code inside nested component - in my case`table-header`

then the code does not work and the colspan attribute does not get applied to the table and does not get the full width of the table.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how the `app-table-header` component is rendered by Angular.  If you look at the result of the table being rendered you will see something like....

#### result of original table render

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="tableHeader" colspan="12">my table header</th>
  </thead>
  <app-table-header>
    <thead>
      <th colspan="12">my table header</th>
    </thead>
  </app-table-header>
</table>
```

When `app-table-header` rendered there is an extra element between the `<table>` and the `<thead>` which breaks the table.

A possible solution is to make `app-table-header` an attribute selector, `[app-table-header]` and use a `thead` in your table with the attribute selector `<thead app-table-header>`.

#### table-header.compnonent.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'thead[app-table-header]',
  templateUrl: './table-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-header.component.css']
})
export class TableHeaderComponent implements {
  @Input()
  public heading: string = '';
}
```

#### table-header.component.html

```html
<!-- Remove the thead from here -->
<th class="tableHeader" colspan="12">{{ heading }}</th>
```

#### table.component.html

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="tableHeader" colspan="12">my table header</th>
  </thead>
  <thead app-table-header heading="Passing heading down with @Input"></thead>
</table>
```

This will result in the below html

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="tableHeader" colspan="12">my table header</th>
  </thead>
  <thead app-table-header>
    <th colspan="12">Passing heading down with @Input</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

See stackblitz below

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bojuuf

**EDIT**

- Updated the selector to `thead[app-table-header]` as suggested by @
  Mazedul Islam.
- Added `@Input()` to show you can pass values down with inputs.
- Updated stackblitz

Comment: This is a great solution. However, I would suggest to update the selector of `TableHeaderComponent` like this: `thead[app-table-header]`. Then it will be a clear indication that, this component should be used with a `thead` host.

Comment: @Jason White Thanks for your comment. Is there some other way ? Because with the following solution you provided, i can't send properties to the table-header, i can't use content projection etc...

Comment: @MazedulIslam Nice catch, updated as suggested.

Comment: @user17190872 Check my edits, you can still pass values down with `@Input()`.  You should still be able to use `<ng-content>` as well.

Comment: @JasonWhite thank you. I accepted your answer. Btw what you think, is there other solution where we can use component like i had the problem in the first case ?

Comment: @user17190872 Not that I'm away of.